# Get the first day of week without WeekCalendarUnit

Tags: swift, nsdate

I would like to get the first day of the week depending on a NSDate.

It works fine but I have a warning because WeekCalendarUnit is deprecated.

I made some research and I tried to replace WeekCalendarUnit with :

```
static var CalendarUnitWeekday: NSCalendarUnit { get }
static var CalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal: NSCalendarUnit { get }
static var CalendarUnitWeekOfMonth: NSCalendarUnit { get }
static var CalendarUnitWeekOfYear: NSCalendarUnit { get }
```

But I don't have the same result. Here is my junk of code :

```
var date = NSDate()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/YY"
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let currentDateComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .WeekCalendarUnit , fromDate: date)
let startOfWeek = calendar.dateFromComponents(currentDateComponents)
var dteString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfWeek!)
// Output is "17/15"
```

Any Idea?

Comment: `.WeekCalendarUnit` should be replaced with `.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @milo526, but if I do that my output is "01/15" ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear` in combination with
`.CalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear`, this should give the intended result:

```
let currentDateComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear | .CalendarUnitWeekOfYear , fromDate: date)
let startOfWeek = calendar.dateFromComponents(currentDateComponents)
```

Alternatively, use `rangeOfUnit()` (which I personally find easier to
use):

```
var startOfWeek : NSDate?
calendar.rangeOfUnit(.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, startDate: &startOfWeek, interval: nil, forDate: date)
```

In **Swift 2** this has to be changed to

```
let currentDateComponents = calendar.components([.YearForWeekOfYear, .WeekOfYear ], fromDate: date)
let startOfWeek = calendar.dateFromComponents(currentDateComponents)
```

and

```
var startOfWeek : NSDate?
calendar.rangeOfUnit(.WeekOfYear, startDate: &startOfWeek, interval: nil, forDate: date)
```

Comment: @MartinR How can this be modified slightly so that it returns Monday as the first day of the week instead of sunday? Also I need to get the final day of the week (Sunday)

Comment: @user2363025: Whether Sunday or Monday is the first day of a week is locale dependent. NSCalendar has a firstWeekday property which you can set to a different value if really necessary.

Comment: @MartinR adding calendar.firstWeekDay = 1 made no effect on the variable startOfWeek. Is there something else i'm missing?

Comment: @user2363025: You have to set `calendar.firstWeekDay = 2` to set Monday as the first day of the week.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how to use the above code, if I want to get the first date of the current week. This code has startOfWeek being used twice which conflicts. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @trever: In the above answer are two code snippets for Swift 1.2 and two code snippets for Swift 2. You should use only *one* of them, e.g. the last one.

Comment: Useful answer and comment by Martin R.