# get first day of week using Weeknumber in Swift

Tags: swift, calendar, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to get the first day of current week (say this week, i should be getting 2015-09-13).

However i cannot find the appropriate function in Apple's provided source code.

code should be something like this...

```
print(getFirstDay(40)) // Should print 27

func getFirstDay(weekNumber:Int)->Int?{
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    if let todayDate = formatter.dateFromString(weekNumber) {
        let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let myComponents = myCalendar.dateFromComponents(.weekOfYear)
        let date = myComponents.date
        return date
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

However above code doesn't work (obviously) but it is something i was thinking of should be in the right direction.

How can i achieve this?

/* Not important */
I am trying to create a sort-of calendar app in a table View which is separated by Sections of 4 weeks, i want to know which date a new week starts at.

Comment: Here is some code to find the first day of a week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330523/get-the-first-day-of-week-without-weekcalendarunit. – But I don't understand your example getFirstDay(40) = 27. 40 is probably the week number in the year, but what is 27?

Comment: 27 is the date the week actually starts at 09/27 (MM-dd), and that link doesn't really help with my problem as it states the 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'

Comment: That was written for Swift 1.2. I am going to update it for Swift 2 now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    func getFirstDay(weekNumber:Int)->String?{
        let Calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let dayComponent = NSDateComponents()
        dayComponent.weekOfYear = weekNumber
        dayComponent.weekday = 1
        dayComponent.year = 2015
        var date = Calendar.dateFromComponents(dayComponent)

        if(weekNumber == 1 && Calendar.components(.Month, fromDate: date!).month != 1){
            print(Calendar.components(.Month, fromDate: date!).month)
            dayComponent.year = 2014
            date = Calendar.dateFromComponents(dayComponent)
        }
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        return String(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!))
    }
```

Very rough code what i did so far.

It works for finding the first day of the week ;)!

Comment: the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659990/get-first-day-of-week-using-weeknumber-in-swift#comment127332676_63997465) below applies here as well

Answer (score 5):

My Solution with Xcode 12 and Swift 5

```
extension Date {

   var year: Int? {
       var calendar = Calendar.current
       let currentComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: self)
       return currentComponents.year
   }
} 

class func getWeekOfYear(from week: Int, year: Int? = Date().year, locale: Locale? = nil) -> Date? {
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.locale = locale
        let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: year, weekday: 1, weekOfYear: week)
        return calendar.date(from: dateComponents)
    }
```

You can run it with:

```
  getWeekOfYear(from: 38)             // Optional(2020-09-13 22:00:00 +0000)
  getWeekOfYear(from: 38, year: 2020) // Optional(2020-09-13 22:00:00 +0000)
  getWeekOfYear(from: 38, year: 2020, locale: Locale(identifier: de_DE) ) // Optional(2020-09-13 22:00:00 +0000)
```

Addons:

```
extension Date {

   func isBetween(_ date1: Date, and date2: Date) -> Bool {
      return (min(date1, date2) ... max(date1, date2)).contains(self)
   }

   var startOfWeek: Date? {
      var calendar = Calendar.current
      return calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfMonth, for: self)?.start
   }

   var endOfWeek: Date? {
       var calendar = Calendar.current
       return calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfMonth, for: self)?.end
   }

   var startOfMonth: Date? {
       var calendar = Calendar.current
       return calendar.dateInterval(of: .month, for: self)?.start
   }

   var endOfMonth: Date? {
       var calendar = Calendar.current
       return calendar.dateInterval(of: .month, for: self)?.end
   }

   var weekNumber: Int? {
       var calendar = Calendar.current
       let currentComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: self)
       return currentComponents.weekOfYear
   }

   var monthNumber: Int? {
       var calendar = Calendar.current
       let currentComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.month], from: self)
       return currentComponents.month
   }
}
```

You can run it with:

```
let date = Date() // Optional(2020-09-13 22:00:00 +0000)
date.monthNumber  // Optional(9)
date.weekNumber   // Optional(38)
```

...

Comment: Calendar has a `component` method if you need just one component. Another issue here is getting the `year` component instead of `yearForWeekOfYear` on your method. In other words you should use `yearForWeekOfYear` along with `weekOfYear`

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error and if you're using Swift3 + iOS10, this is the correct solution. This calculates the correct date on Dec/Jan crossing boundaries.

```
extension Date {
    var components:DateComponents {
        let cal = NSCalendar.current
        return cal.dateComponents(Set([.year, .month, .day, .hour,.minute, .second, .weekday, .weekOfYear, .yearForWeekOfYear]),from: self)
    }
}

private static func getWeekFirstDay(from sourceDate:Date) -> Date? {
let Calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)!
    var sourceComp = sourceDate.components
    var comp = DateComponents()
    comp.weekOfYear = sourceComp.weekOfYear
    comp.weekday = 1
    comp.yearForWeekOfYear = sourceComp.yearForWeekOfYear
    return Calendar.date(from: comp)
}
```

Comment: I get sourceDate has no member components in Swift 3

Comment: i forgot to add my `Date` extension. fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitWeekOfYear | .CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: NSDate())

components.calendar = calendar

components.weekday = 2 // 2 = Monday
components.weekOfYear = 39

let firstDayOfWeek = components.date
```

This gives you the date of the monday in the 39th week of the current year.

Comment: the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659990/get-first-day-of-week-using-weeknumber-in-swift#comment127332676_63997465) below applies here as well

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4.2

More generic solution

```
func getFirstDay(WeekNumber weekNumber:Int, CurrentYear currentYear: Int)->String?{
    let Calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)!
    var dayComponent = DateComponents()
    dayComponent.weekOfYear = weekNumber
    dayComponent.weekday = 1
    dayComponent.year = currentYear
    var date = Calendar.date(from: dayComponent)
    
    if(weekNumber == 1 && Calendar.components(.month, from: date!).month != 1){
        //print(Calendar.components(.month, from: date!).month)
        dayComponent.year = currentYear - 1
        date = Calendar.date(from: dayComponent)
    }
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    return String(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))
}
```

Comment: the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659990/get-first-day-of-week-using-weeknumber-in-swift#comment127332676_63997465) below applies here as well