# List of Days of this week

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, nsdate

I need a list of days of the week (with the week starting on Monday) for a timecard list. Im not sure how to achieve this. I have tried some dateByAddingUnit and subtracting from there but it hasn't produced the results I want.

Any idea how to get a list of the dates? (i.e. Monday would be 3/28/16, Tuesday 3/29/16 and so on)

Comment: Code! Give us code. Edit your question and post what you tried.

Comment: Try searching SO for DayOfWeek.

Comment: Well I guess here is a way I could do it but I don't understand the code, if anyone can explain? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330523/get-the-first-day-of-week-without-weekcalendarunit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: missed that you want a week to always start on a Monday

```
let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let today = gregorian.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

let startOfWeek: NSDate    
if gregorian.component(.Weekday, fromDate: today) == 2 {
    // Today is Monday
    startOfWeek = today
} else {
    // Find the last Monday prior to today
    startOfWeek = gregorian.nextDateAfterDate(today, matchingUnit: .Weekday, value: 2, options: [.SearchBackwards, .MatchPreviousTimePreservingSmallerUnits])!
}
```